# Sturm-Liouville problem eigenvalues

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Solve the S-L

$-(xX')' = \frac{\lambda}{ x} X \quad , 1<x<e$

$X'(1)-X(1) = 0 \quad , X'(e) + 10 X(e) = 0$

What are the three least eigenvalues $\lambda_1 , \lambda_2 , \lambda_3$ ?

How can I find these. Thanks!

I know we must check whether or not the eigenvalues can be negative and such....

Answer (score 0):

First consider the case $\lambda=0$. Then we may integrate the ODE immediately to obtain

$$xX'=c_1, c_1\in\mathbb{C} \implies X'=\frac{c_1}{x}\implies X=c_1\ln x+c_2$$

At $x=1$, $X(1)=c_2, X'(1)=c_1$ hence the boundary condition requires that $c_1=c_2$. At $x=e$, $X(e)=c_1+c_2, X'(e)=\frac{c_1}{e}$ hence the boundary condition requires that $\frac{c_1}{e}+10(c_1+c_2)=0\implies c_2=-\frac{c_1}{10 e}-c_1$. Solving these two boundary condition equations simultaneously, we obtain $c_1=c_2=0$, which is the trivial zero solution, and hence we reject $\lambda=0$.

Now consider $\lambda\neq 0$. Expand the ODE: 
$$xX''+X'+\frac{\lambda}{x}X=0 \\
\implies X''+\frac{X'}{x}+\lambda\frac{X}{x^2}=0$$.

which is clearly an Euler ODE. Note that the coefficients are continuous and well-behaved on the interval $[1,e]$ desired.

The solutions are of the form $X=x^r$. Substitute this ansatz into the ODE to obtain the characteristic equation for $r$:

$$r(r-1)x^{r-2}+rx^{r-2}+\lambda x^{r-2}=0 \\
\implies r(r-1)+r+\lambda=0 \\
\implies r=\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}$$

Hence the general homogenous solution looks like:

$$X=c_1 x^{i\sqrt{\lambda}}+c_2x^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

since the roots are distinct as $\lambda\neq 0$. We can rewrite this solution:

$$X=c_1 e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x}+c_2e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x} \\
\implies X=d_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x)+d_2\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\ln x)$$

with $d_1=c_1-c_2,d_2=c_1+c_2$. Now consider the boundary conditions:

$$X(1)=d_2, X'(1)=d_1\sqrt{\lambda} \implies d_1\sqrt{\lambda}-d_2=0$$

$$
X(e)=d_1\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+d_2\cos\sqrt{\lambda}, X'(e)=\frac{d_1}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}-\frac{d_2}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}$$

$$\implies \frac{d_1}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}-\frac{d_2}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+10(d_1\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+d_2\cos\sqrt{\lambda})=0$$

Combining,

$$ \frac{d_1}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}-\frac{d_1\sqrt{\lambda}}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+10(d_1\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+d_1\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda})=0$$.

We disallow $d_1=0$ since that will give $d_2=0$ as well and hence result in the trivial zero solution. Hence,

$$ \frac{1}{e}\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}-\frac{1}{e}\lambda\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+10\sin\sqrt{\lambda}+10\sqrt{\lambda}\cos\sqrt{\lambda}=0$$

$$\implies (\sin\sqrt{\lambda})\left(10-\frac{\lambda}{e}\right)+(\cos\sqrt{\lambda})\left(\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{e}+10\sqrt{\lambda}\right)=0$$

This is a transcendental equation for $\lambda$. Note that by Sturm-Liouville theory, all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ will be real. We check for possible negative $\lambda$, which will result in purely imaginary $\sqrt{\lambda}$ with $|\sqrt{\lambda}|>0$:

$$i\sinh|\sqrt{\lambda}|(10-\frac{i|\lambda|}{e})+\cosh|\sqrt{\lambda}|\left(\frac{i|\sqrt{\lambda|}}{e}+10i|\sqrt{\lambda}|\right)=0$$

We immediately observe that the real part of this equation is $\frac{|\lambda|}{e}\sinh|\sqrt{\lambda}|=0$. But since we have disallowed $\lambda=0$, we require $\sinh|\sqrt{\lambda}|=0$. But this has exactly one solution at $|\sqrt{\lambda}|=0$. Hence there are no negative $\lambda$ solutions.

Now go back to the positive $\lambda$ equation. It is not possible to solve for the roots of $(\sin\sqrt{\lambda})\left(10-\frac{\lambda}{e}\right)+(\cos\sqrt{\lambda})\left(\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{e}+10\sqrt{\lambda}\right)$ analytically. However, we may plot this function graphically and observe that the roots are isolated, non-repeated and can be put in a one-one relation with the natural numbers (hence there is a countable infinity of them on the positive $\lambda$ axis). Depending on your course, you may have to prove these statements with a bit of real analysis, but it shouldn't be hard.

The first three roots are around $\lambda=3.88, 22.5,59.4$. Let the values of $\lambda$ that satisfy the transcendental equation be indexed by $n$, so that the eigenvalues of the ODE are $\lambda_n,n=1,2,\ldots,$.

Returning to the first boundary condition, we hence have the ratio of $d_2$ to $d_1$ to be $\sqrt{\lambda}$. Hence the eigenfunctions look like:

$$X_n=d_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\ln x)+d_1\sqrt{\lambda_n}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}\ln x)$$

where $d_1$ is a constant you can choose so that the weighted inner product is normalised:

$$\int_1^e \frac{1}{x}X_nX_mdx=\begin{cases} 0, m\neq n \\ 1, m=n\end{cases}$$

The general solution of the homogeneous Sturm-Liouville problem is hence a linear superposition of all these eigenfunctions.